# How can I get only the classes and subclasses from an ontology using the class Model?

Tags: jena

I know how to do it using the OntModel, but the problem with this constructor is that I am getting also the classes from the imported ontologies, and I only want to get the classes and subclasses from the BaseModel.
If I use the method listSubjects() I also get the properties and I dont want them.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what, if you only want results from the base model, you'll have to get the base model from the `OntModel` with `OntModel.getBaseModel`.  If the base model also happens to be an `OntModel`, you could simply cast it:

```java
OntModel model = ...;
OntModel base = (OntModel) model.getBaseModel();
```

If the other classes are coming from *submodels* (which are not exactly the same as ontologies imported by `owl:imports`, though ontologies imported with `owl:imports` will be submodels of the `OntModel`), you could just create a new `OntModel` with the same base model, but none of the other submodels:

```java
OntModel model = ...;
OntModel wrappedBase 
  = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( model.getSpecification(), 
                                      model.getBaseModel() );
```

and then use `wrappedBase` to list the classes and subclasses you're interested in.  If you really don't want a second `OntModel`, then you could ask for the statements in the base model that represent the things you're interested in, but this will require knowledge of how the ontology language represents classes.  OWL models are probably the most common, so you could do something like:

```java
OntModel model = ...;
Model base = model.getBaseModel();
... = base.listStatements( null, RDF.type, OWL.Class );
... = base.listStatements( null, RDFS.subClassOf, null );
```

and work with those statements.  The first two approaches will be easier, of course.